# Why did the Centauri Emperor Turhan look more human than Centauri, given that he lacks the Centauri peacock hair?

Tags: babylon-5

Every Centauri I saw on Babylon 5 had this peacock hair. Surprisingly, the figure-head of Centauri Prime looks nothing like them. His hair and face look absolutely human. Why does he look so different from all the other Centauris? Where is his peacock hair?

[image]

Comment: The wiki says "He rejected the vanity shown by many upper-class Centauri by refusing to wear a wig during his visit to Babylon 5" but this doesn't appear to be sourced.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Coming of Shadows. - "*2x9: The Coming of Shadows recap: On Centauri Prime, Prime Minister Malachi informs Emperor Turhan that everything is ready and the Royal Liner is standing by for departure. Turhan tells Malachi that he will remain on Centauri Prime, ignoring his friend's objections. Malachi warns the Emperor that his condition is delicate, but Turhan believes that he can wait no longer. **Turhan refuses to don his traditional Centauri wig and thanks Malachi for his service***"

Comment: Are we to take, then, that the "peacock hair" is not the Centauri natural hair and that they just wear wigs to show off their status?

Comment: @colmde The wig was more likely due to age/hair loss.  The style and length of the hair/wig was about status though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

His wig is left back on Centauri Prime. In *B5: Coming of Shadows*, we learn that he sees it as a form of vanity and just point-blank refuses to wear it.

> **Turhan:** *No need for that now. When you get to be as old as I, the trappings of status are not as important as they used to be.*

[image]

You may wish to note that his nephew Cartagia also has much the same opinion and wears his (evidently real) hair shockingly short.

Comment: In Cartagia's case I suspect this is [countersignaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countersignaling) rather than modesty. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - They both do it for the shock-value, but for different reasons.